# Issue while changing font size/family using media query bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have a font size of 30px in the medium size screen, but i needed to reduce the size of font size to 10px in extra small screen so i tried using media query.

But i am facing an unusual issue here, if i try to change the background colour it is working but the font size change is not working.

Following is the my CSS:-

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(../fonts/JosefinSlab-regular.ttf);
 }

.frontback{
font-family:myFirstFont;
font-size:30px;
margin-top:10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.frontback{
       font-family:myFirstFont;
        font-size:10px;     
        background-color:red;
   }       
}
```

The background colour is getting changed when i reduce the screen size but font size is not getting changed. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Your media query still says: `font-size:30px;`?

Comment: i forgot to edit.. just did it now

Comment: your code is working according to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/cjs0v4w6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.frontback{
       font-family: myFirstFont;
        font-size: 10px !important;     
        background-color:red;
   }       
}
```

Please try this :)

Comment: this works if i added !important.. can you please  tell why is that required?

Comment: Please tick if it helped. Actually its about preference. You must have a more specific selector on .frontback and it was getting over rided because of that. When you add !important, it becomes the most preferred and over ride every other styling.